# Send MQTT incoming package (Paho) to void function

Tags: c++, function, mqtt, void, paho

I cannot send an incoming mqtt package (Paho MQTT) to a void function `send`. I can receive it in `receive` but I need to send it again in `send()`

cpp

```
void MqttApplication::mqttReceive()
{

    try {
        cout << "\subscribing to topics..." << endl;
        mqttClient->start_consuming();
        mqttClient->subscribe(TOPIC, QOS)->wait();
        cout << "...OK" << endl;
    }
    catch (const mqtt::exception& exc) {
        cerr << exc.what() << endl;
        return;
    }

    while (true) {
        auto msg = mqttClient->consume_message();
        if (!msg) {
            if (!mqttClient->is_connected()) {
                cout << "lost connection" << endl;
                if (mqttTryReconnect(*mqttClient)) {
                    mqttClient->subscribe(TOPIC, QOS);
                    cout << "application reconnected" << endl;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "application reconnect failed." << endl;
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "error occurred." << endl;
            }
            break;
        }

        try {
            send(mqtt::const_message_ptr consume_message());
        }
        catch (const mqtt::exception& exc) {
            cerr << exc.what() << endl;
            return;
        }

        if (msg->get_topic() == "command" && msg->to_string() == "exit") {
            cout << "Exit command received" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << msg->get_topic() << ": " << msg->to_string() << endl;
    }
}

void MqttApplication::send(mqtt::const_message_ptr* msg)
{
    doc.Parse(msg->to_string())
}
```

hpp

```
void send(mqtt::const_message_ptr* msg);
```

I get these errors:

```
 error: expected primary-expression before ‘consume_message’
  286 |             send(mqtt::const_message_ptr consume_message());
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 error: ‘using const_message_ptr = using const_ptr_t = class std::shared_ptr<const mqtt::message>’ {aka ‘class std::shared_ptr<const mqtt::message>’} has no member named ‘to_string’
  326 |     doc.Parse(msg->to_string());
```

`consume_message()`:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you just want `send(consume_message())`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, if I put only consume_message() the errors says it was not declared.

Comment: it looks like `receive` isn't a member function but `send` is? please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles i've added missing part, the receiver part works and mqtt messages are received correctly

Comment: We're still lacking a [mre], what is `consume_message` for example

Comment: @AlanBirtles consume_message is a Paho MQTT function which awaits for a MQTT message

Comment: That's a member of the client though? You aren't calling a member of `mqttClient`? Should it just be `mqttClient->consume_message()`?